# How to deal with multiple parentheses in content with regex

Tags: regex

#### content

`2023-04-20 Rate (123 3 Days) JPY 13900 genius=no\n2023-04-21 Rate (123 3 Days) JPY 14900 genius=no\n2023-04-22 Rate (123 3 Days) JPY 16900 genius=no\n`

#### pattern

`(\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})\s\w+\s\(\d+\s\d+\s+\w+\)\s(\w+)\s(\d+)`

I want to split each line like `2023-04-20 Rate (123 3 Days) JPY 13900`, and get the date, currency, and price, this pattern works fine, but actually, the string within the parentheses might be changed, so I have to ignore what it has inside if I change the pattern to: `(\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})\s\w+\s\(.*\)\s(\w+)\s(\d+)`, I only get one data because it calculates the whole string between the first and the last parentheses, is it possible to ignore what's in the parentheses and get each line of the content consistent to the pattern?

Comment: Did you mean to make it non greedy? `.*?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the match non-greedy, `\(.*?\)`:

```
(\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})\s\w+\s\(.*?\)\s(\w+)\s(\d+)
```

Or simply, match on anything except `)` with `\([^)]*\)`:

```
(\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})\s\w+\s\([^)]*\)\s(\w+)\s(\d+)
```

Comment: remarkable, you save my day, may I ask the concept about the \([^)]*\)?

Comment: @Chan You're welcome! `[^`...`]`  matches on anything _not_ in the character group. So, `[^ace]`  would match on any character except `a`, `c` and `e`. This makes it perfect for this since you actually want all characters up to the first `)` encountered.

Comment: both answers were perfect, thanks a lot